# Text not rendered on Safari when applied with custom SVG filter via CSS

Tags: css, safari, svg-filters

I wrote a custom SVG filter to draw strokes around text and icons. The filter is then referred in the CSS stylesheet. The following code renders as expected in Chrome and Firefox, but it hides the content entirely on Safari.

Did I miss anything in the filter definition?

```css
.text {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: 3rem;
  filter: url(#filter);
  color: #0044aa;
}
```

```html
<svg width="0" height="0" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" style="position: absolute; visibility: hidden;">
  <filter id="filter" x="-20%" y="-20%" width="140%" height="140%" filterUnits="objectBoundingBox" primitiveUnits="userSpaceOnUse" color-interpolation-filters="sRGB">
      <feMorphology operator="dilate" radius="3 3" x="0%" y="0%" width="100%" height="100%" in="SourceGraphic" result="morphology"/>
      <feFlood flood-color="#ff8822" flood-opacity="1" x="0%" y="0%" width="100%" height="100%" result="flood"/>
      <feComposite in="flood" in2="morphology" operator="in" x="0%" y="0%" width="100%" height="100%" result="composite2"/>
      <feMerge x="0%" y="0%" width="100%" height="100%" result="merge">
          <feMergeNode in="composite2"/>
          <feMergeNode in="SourceGraphic"/>
      </feMerge>
  </filter>
</svg>
<div class="text">
    Lorem ipsum
    <img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAsAAAAKAgMAAAAfnkwQAAAAA3NCSVQICAjb4U/gAAAACVBMVEX///8kUmQkUmTp7WYpAAAAA3RSTlMAu//QRVwgAAAACXBIWXMAAAsSAAALEgHS3X78AAAAHHRFWHRTb2Z0d2FyZQBBZG9iZSBGaXJld29ya3MgQ1M0BrLToAAAABZ0RVh0Q3JlYXRpb24gVGltZQAwOC8xMi8xMKNAeX0AAAAnSURBVAiZY2BgDGFgYEhhEHWcwiDA5sIgIMnAICACxAwOcCwa6gAATVoD5WIuD5EAAAAASUVORK5CYII=" />
</div>
```

Comment: Looks like it doesn't like  the percentage `width` and `height` in the `feFlood`.

Comment: Dropping `x`, `y`, `width` and `height` did the trick. Thank you @Kaiido !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Removing all the `x`, `y`, `width`, and `height` attributes from the filter nodes did the trick. Thanks @Kaiido for the comment!

```css
.text {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: 3rem;
  filter: url(#filter);
  color: #0044aa;
}
```

```html
<svg width="0" height="0" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" style="position: absolute; visibility: hidden;">
  <filter id="filter" filterUnits="objectBoundingBox" primitiveUnits="userSpaceOnUse" color-interpolation-filters="sRGB">
      <feMorphology operator="dilate" radius="3 3" in="SourceGraphic" result="morphology"/>
      <feFlood flood-color="#ff8822" flood-opacity="1" result="flood"/>
      <feComposite in="flood" in2="morphology" operator="in" result="composite2"/>
      <feMerge result="merge">
          <feMergeNode in="composite2"/>
          <feMergeNode in="SourceGraphic"/>
      </feMerge>
  </filter>
</svg>
<div class="text">
  Lorem ipsum
  <img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAsAAAAKAgMAAAAfnkwQAAAAA3NCSVQICAjb4U/gAAAACVBMVEX///8kUmQkUmTp7WYpAAAAA3RSTlMAu//QRVwgAAAACXBIWXMAAAsSAAALEgHS3X78AAAAHHRFWHRTb2Z0d2FyZQBBZG9iZSBGaXJld29ya3MgQ1M0BrLToAAAABZ0RVh0Q3JlYXRpb24gVGltZQAwOC8xMi8xMKNAeX0AAAAnSURBVAiZY2BgDGFgYEhhEHWcwiDA5sIgIMnAICACxAwOcCwa6gAATVoD5WIuD5EAAAAASUVORK5CYII="
  />
</div>
```

Comment: Note that when you define primitiveUnits = userSpaceOnUse - Safari expects dimensions to be expressed in userSpaceUnits - not %'s. If you follow the spec (which Chrome doesn't) - you can't mix and match %'s and userSpaceUnits within a single filter.

Answer (score 0):

The way that works for me is to use inline styles. Store styles of text in the same file as your svg component:

```
<svg width="0" height="0" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" style="position: absolute; visibility: hidden;">
                 <text filter="url(#filter)">
                     Lorem ipsum
                 </text>
              <defs>
              <filter id="filter" filterUnits="objectBoundingBox" primitiveUnits="userSpaceOnUse" color-interpolation-filters="sRGB">
                  <feMorphology operator="dilate" radius="3 3" in="SourceGraphic" result="morphology"/>
                  <feFlood flood-color="#ff8822" flood-opacity="1" result="flood"/>
                  <feComposite in="flood" in2="morphology" operator="in" result="composite2"/>
                  <feMerge result="merge">
                      <feMergeNode in="composite2"/>
                      <feMergeNode in="SourceGraphic"/>
                  </feMerge>
              </filter>
              </defs>
            </svg>
```